# Regex to recognise a specific language element

Tags: regex

I have to create a specific regex, the thing is whatever I've tried wont work out in the end.
I've seen similar posts using the negative lookbehind to solve this, but in my version apparently it is not supported.

The regex I have to create should:

> recognise identifiers that may start with underscore, followed MANDATORY by a
> alphabetical character, followed by one or more alphanumeric or underscore
> characters. It is essential that the string CANNOT END with
> underscore.

I have tried this `_*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[^_]$` but it won't work for all the cases.

Also this solution with the negative lookbehind creates me issues `_*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$(?<!_)`

some examples of accepted cases:

1. a5
2. _a5___v3
3. a5_v2_2

and non accepted

1. 5_v_2
2. a5_v2_
3. _5_v_2
4. _5
5. a_
6. a5--v-2

Comment: "but it won't work for all the cases." what cases?  Do we have to re-do your research?   (see: https://regex101.com/r/VokrKi/1 which seems to work ok for the cases you provided )

Comment: Like this? `^_*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$` https://regex101.com/r/uspWT2/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> may start with underscore

Use `_?` not `_*`

> followed MANDATORY by a alphabetical character

`[a-zA-Z]` looks good depending on what alphabets are acceptable

> followed by one or more alphanumeric or underscore characters.

Let's use `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*` with a `*` not a `+` because:

> It is essential that the string CANNOT END with underscore

Here is the last chunk `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Final result: `_?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: I hadn't thought of this,I was convinced that ending is binded with the $ symbol,this is a nice approach,thanks !

Comment: This is to match/extract a part of the string, if the string should contain the id and nothing else, use `^_?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$`